# Why can't I edit the question title when editing via the Help & Improvement Queue?

Tags: support, title, help-improvement

I just discovered the H&I (triage?) queue today.

I hit the edit button presented to me by the queue itself in order to salvage some questions, but I noted that I could not edit the title of these questions.  The title presented is text, linking to the question, not an editable form field.  I definitely encountered some questions which could have been improved by having a better title, but I would have had to step out of the queue to do this.

If the point of this queue is to help make questions more palatable, why are we restricted to only being able to edit the body after hitting the queue's edit button?

Comment: Why can't you?  The title can be edited right above where the tags are.  Or does it suppress title changes?

Comment: I'd get a screencap for you, but the queue is empty.

Comment: The title is a link to the question, not an editable field.

Comment: And there is a separate field below the body of the question but above the tags to edit the title.

Comment: I'll have to check that.  Perhaps that is an unintuitive place to put it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can already change the title.  The title is located below the body summary of the question and above the tags.  See this picture:

> [image: H&I view]

Explanation

1. The existing title is a link to the actual question
2. This is where you edit the title
3. Context help that changes based on which part of the question you are editing.  Since focus is on the title, it gives advice for editing the title.

Comment: Thanks.  I must have missed it.  That is kind of a lousy place for the title.

Comment: Not the most intuitive, but I think it was supposed to mirror a workflow.  Something about the fact that editing the body first would lead you to a better title than the other way around.

Answer (score 7):

This isn't a bad question.

We moved the title field below the question body in hopes that it would result in more substantive and effective title edits. You need the context of the question in order to really formulate a good title; we worried that starting folks at the title would result in:

- Fixes in capitalization (which help)
- Fixes in punctuation (which help)
- Fixes in spelling and grammar (which help)
- No real fixes in the wording of the title, so that it more appropriately conveys the main point of the question (which really, really hurts)

The idea is, after you've read the question and worked with the contents a bit, you'd be more inclined and inspired to totally gut the title if needed, and replace it with something likely to attract an expert watching one of the tags.

We still very much believe this is the most efficient order, but if it wasn't immediately obvious to you that you could edit the title at all, it strongly suggests some issues with how it's presented. Since it's different than any other place you'd go to edit something on the site, it makes sense to be less subtle about why the placement is different.

We're wrapping up some pretty thorough (and manual) tests on the efficacy of Triage now, because more than half of the questions sent to the helper queue don't belong there. More than half are either unsalvageable, or, in the minority case, not really in need of any help. Once we're more certain of the input, we're going to take a look at how we can better optimize the interface. To that, we're looking at some tweaks to some wording in Triage among other things early next week.

Comment: I almost expected to be able to click the title text and it would transform into an edit box, which again would match no other site functionality. Alternately an "edit title" button to the right of the linked title, which would cause the edit form to appear (replacing, or immediately below the existing title for reference) might work and have the same result you are looking for.